# Can't seem to get ubuntu-desktop / gnome GUI in vnc?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, user-interface, gnome, vnc

Currently i'm installing a gui on my vps but i can't seem to get the actual desktop layout like it should be in vnc.

in installed (sudo apt-get install) these things: ubuntu-desktop, gdm, tightvncserver

when i login a only get a cmd box in the theme of gnome.. there is no start-menu or anything like that. How do i fix this? My current ~/.vnc/xstartup file is:
[code]#!/bin/sh

## Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:

unset SESSION_MANAGER

## exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc

gnome-session --session=gnome-classic &

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
x-window-manager &
gnome-session &
[/code]

The reason i want a GUI is because i want to be able to view the live cmd of a java service.  The cmd prints (in windows) who has been logged in on the server (from a game i run).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
sudo apt-get install vino
```

you can configure it with

```
vino-preferences
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, using vino doesn't change anything to the desktop i get in vnc. It's still only the cmd.

Comment: Is tightVNC still running? Normally vino works only with a logged in user and with GTK+.

Comment: Yes it is. At this moment i don't have a cmd at all in vnc :/

Comment: Please, can you give me more information. Is `/usr/lib/vino/vino-serve` running?

Comment: at this moment my cmd in vnc went away so i'm unable to start vino-server through putty.

Comment: The vino-server needs a gnome session. You have to configure it with vino-preferences. If you haven't got a gome session you can not start it. (Sorry, it's late now in my timezone. I will answer any questions tomorrow)

Comment: how to i start a gnome session through putty?

Comment: Sorry, I think there was a missunderstanding of your enviroment. It seems to me that you have a headless system. So remove vino and follow the Ubuntu wike http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1714110 . Hope that helps

Comment: Sorry but i still have the same grey screen without cmd in vnc. It doesn't seem to load a GUI when it's connected over vnc.

Comment: Is `gnome-session` running?

Comment: What says the log file?

Comment: I try it by my self with a new server. You have also to install the package `uninti-2d-panel`, `unity-2d-shell` and `gconf2`